# How write this rule using Bolt for Firebase?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to write this rule using Bolt:

```
`
{
"rules": {
    "menu": {
      "$id": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": 
            "root.child('stores')
                .child(newData.child('store')
                .val())
                .child('user').hasChild(auth.uid)"
      }
   }
  }
}
`
```

I need some help, I can't find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This video covers basic Firebase Security Rules including read, write, index and validation statements. It also shows how to write your rules more efficiently with the Bolt compiler
https://youtu.be/fwDK6E1j9nc?t=768